# Julia ccall: Problem with shared library interfacing hardware devices

Tags: c, julia, hardware

I am using Julia to control a camera which comes with a shared library on Linux-Mint. The shared library provides APIs written in C++. There are also header files containing definitions of types and constants concerning the device. I wrote Julia scripts to wrap C structs, definitions, enums and types with Julia. Here is the critical point. I use ccall function to call a function in the shared library . This function is supposed to return an opaque handle of the device. I use this format variant `ccall( (:function, "library"), ...)`. An error code saying **no camera is** found was thrown back. Then, I tried preloading the shared library using `Libdl.dlopen` and use `ccall(:function,..., ...)` to call the function, but still got the same result. The same operation works perfectly fine in C.

I am wondering what could block connection to hardware devices when using `ccall`. I do not know the details of `ccall` implementation in Julia. If anybody can give me some clues, that would be great help.

Have a nice day,

Sitthichat

Comment: As a thought, you might try something like https://github.com/JuliaInterop/CxxWrap.jl or https://github.com/eschnett/CxxInterface.jl

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that would interfere with the actual communication with the camera though, so would more suspect either some dependency of the librayr that is not being found, or an issue with something being passed to the `ccall`